# Как задать максимальное значение для оси X?

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

При вычислении процентов мне необходимо чтобы максимальное значение оси X было 100 как показано здесь:
[image]

Для своей диаграммы я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
chartt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 100;
```

Но получаю вот это
[image]

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3):

`chartt1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?